# SharePoint 2019 Development which version of Visual Studio to download Enterprise or Professional?

Tags: development, visual-studio, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

For developing Solutions for SharePoint 2019 which version of visual studio can i download according to article it shows it supports Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.

[MS documentation here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-2019-development-platform).

[Visual Studio documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes).

*Which version can i download Enterprise or Professional?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either one as both support the SharePoint development. Yes you need Visual Studio 2017 v 15.9 as this build include the project for SharePoint 2019 (you can also migrate your old 2016 or 2013 SP projects).

to learn more about difference between Visual Studio offering, please check this: [Compare Visual Studio 2017 IDEs](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/)

Comment: >>Yes you need Visual Studio 2017 v 15.9 as this build include the project for SharePoint 2019 - is it OOTB or I need to install something else there? I don't see "2019" projects there..

Comment: Ups.. I installed "Office / SharePoint Development" section for VS and it appeared. Sorry!)